# DateTime.Now precision when called in different services

Tags: c#, date, precision

I have an object which can be called MyResponse.

```
{
"TimeStampA": "2022-01-01 08:00:00.000",
"TimeStampB": "2022-01-01 08:00:00.100"
}
```

The response is created by a service A (which set `TimeStampA` property) and then forwarded to service B (which set `TimeStampB` property).
Service A and service B are running on the same server.

`TimeStampA` and `TimeStampB` are both set using `DateTime.Now` function.

Problem : when the frequency of MyResponse publication is very high, i can see that in some cases, `TimeStampB < TimeStampA`

I found this article telling that `DateTime.Now` can return the same value if called repeatedly in a short time interval.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_DateTime_Now
It seems to explain why `TimeStampB < TimeStampA` in some cases ?

So, how to set the timestamp with precision ? Stopwatch seems more appropriate for durations, but the items are manipulated in 2 services.

My goal is to calculate the duration between `TimeStampA` and `TimeStampB`

Thanks

Comment: I find it strange still that B is strictly less than A, while being called later. The same would be no surprise, but why less?

Comment: How do you store and compare the timestamps? Ad DateTime, as string?

Comment: It is technically possible.  The clock gets updated by the OS clock interrupt handler, it ticks 64 times per second by default.  Recent versions of Windows allow that default to be changed and limit the affect to a specific process.  Documented in the article for timeBeginPeriod().  In general, differences of 16 msec or less should be ignored.

Comment: What precision are you aiming for? Even if we rule out the "overtaking" problem,  maybe `DateTime.Now` may be not sufficiently accurate for what you want to achieve?

Comment: Timestamps are store as datetimes. Sometimes, TimeStampB is 5-10ms earlier than TimeStampA. Ideally I'm looking for 1ms precision.

Comment: What happens to those dates between that DateTime.Now assignment and the comparison? Could they possibly go through JSON or XML where they could lose fractions of a second?